# Coalesce and IsNULL in a Concat not working with NULL valies

Tags: mysql, coalesce, isnull, ifnull

I am trying to create a string out of several fields, some of which can be NULL. If I do

```
Select Concat(FieldA,IsNULL(FieldB,''),FIeldC) from Table
```

I get

> 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function
> 'IsNULL'

If I do

```
Select Concat(FieldA,Coalesce(FieldB,''),FIeldC) from Table
```

I get NULL records where FieldB is NULL I even tried for the heck of it:

```
 Select Concat(FieldA,IFNULL(FieldB,''),FIeldC) from Table
```

and got empty records again

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but I thought the whole point was to return either the record value or an empty value on NULL records to avoid null returns

Comment: In some databases the empty string is considered NULL. Try to change '' to 'test' and see what happens.

Comment: In MySql ISNULL() takes only 1 argument: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull If your last 2 queries return null then check also the columns FieldA and FieldC for nulls.

Comment: @forpas Thanks, however now instead of error message it returns NULL records where FIeldB is NULL

Comment: @ewramner Tried that with `Coalesce` since `IsNULL() ` only allows the field parameter and still got NULL records.

Comment: Concat() returns null only if any of its arguments is null. So you must have nulls in the other columns.

Comment: @forpas Ok my bad there were three places in the actuall query (long one) where the FieldB was called thus is appeared even with the fix it was returning `NULL` records. I fixed each one to do just `IsNUL(FIeldB)` and it works fine. Thanks, upvoted, feel free to make official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Fine if it is solved.

Comment: Provide an example online fiddle based on your structure and data.

Comment: @forpas FWIW, the IsNULL returned ' 0 ' which doesn't work for me. I saw a bunch of solutions using `CAST` however to simplify (for me at least) I just wrapped the `Concat` inside a `Replace` so e.g. `Concat(FieldA,IsNULL(FIeldB))` became `Replace(Concat(FieldA,IsNULL(FIeldB)),' 0 ','')`

Comment: Don't use ISNULL() because it only returns 1 or 0. Use COALESCE(FIeldB, '').

Comment: @forpas Yeah I just found that ou the hard way :) thanks